# How can I change the code so that it outputs my prompt?

Tags: java

Trying to write a program where it outputs the user entered number if it is between 30 and 70.If not, it should prompt the user to reenter. This is what I have so far, but the code is not running at all.

What should I change?

I tried debugging but it seems like it just gives me random quick fixes that jumble up my original code.

here is the code:

```
package chpt5_project;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class chpt5_project {

    //variables
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int count1 = input.nextInt();
        
         while (count1 > 70 || count1 < 30){
        System.out.println("Enter a value between 30 and 70: ");
            
        input.close();
    }
            
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't post code as screenshots. Post it as text.

Comment: If you want to repeatedly read input, the "read input" part should go into the loop, right?

Answer (score 1):

Move `input.nextInt()` into the `while` loop and don't close `input` until after the loop

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int count1 = 0;
    
    while (count1 > 70 || count1 < 30){

        System.out.print("Enter a value between 30 and 70: ");

        count1 = input.nextInt();
    
    }

    input.close();
        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
// no need to close Scanner for System.in
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

// create an loop
while (true) {
    System.out.print("Enter a value between 30 and 70: ");
    int num = scan.nextInt();
    
    // exit the loop if number is correct
    if (num > 30 && num < 70)
        break;
}
```